# Extend datagrid highlighted row to right edge of datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF datagrid and it looks like this:

[image]

At the end of the last column, the row highlighting also ends. I would like it to continue to the right edge of the datagrid control.

Playing with the `SelectionMode` and `SelectionUnit` have done nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding a style to my row:

```
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="DataGridRow.IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#8cc5ff" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```